# Why does Kubernetes Flux need multiple configuration intervals?

Tags: kubernetes, flux, kustomize

I am new to Flux.
I struggle to understand the interval configuration. I am following the original doc [Flux](https://fluxcd.io/docs/get-started/#before-you-begin)

```
flux create source git podinfo \
--url=https://github.com/stefanprodan/podinfo \
--branch=master \
--interval=30s \
--export > ./clusters/my-cluster/podinfo-source.yaml

flux create kustomization podinfo \
--target-namespace=default \
--source=podinfo \
--path="./kustomize" \
--prune=true \
--interval=5m \
--export > ./clusters/my-cluster/podinfo-kustomization.yaml
```

The former interval (30s) should control how often flux looks at Git for new commits, whereas the latter interval (5m) controls how often flux will apply what’s in git to the cluster, regardless of new commits. This is how, for example, a resource deleted using other means will be re-created.

Question: what's the point to have 2 intervals? My best guess: is it because without the former interval Kustomize would have **no** way to eventually update the manifests in the path it is observing? Rather it will **only** be able to reconcile manual changes in the k8s cluster ?!

Answer (score 1):

In the first command you are creating a git repository (kubernetes CRD) this will instrument flux to check all 30s for updates on the defined repository.
If there is a change it will be applied to all referenced items in the cluster.

Independent of changes on git level, there can be drifts in your cluster (f.e. by changing things manually.)

Your 2nd command is creating a flux kustomization, with an interval of 5m. The kustomization interval is independent of the git interval. Even if no changes in git are pushed within the last 5m, flux will reconcile the path and all involved resources each 5m.

Keep in mind that this does not include HelmReleases resources output. (This is really hard to understand at the begining and I personally wonderd a lot why things dont get reconciled after reconsiling the kustomization level) For further reading and configuration for flux helm drift detection and correction check the documentation: https://fluxcd.io/flux/components/helm/helmreleases/#drift-detection

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have found the answer here https://fluxcd.io/docs/flux-e2e/.
Essentially the Kustomize controller is the only responsible to apply changes to the cluster including the new commits coming from the Source Controller. Hence they fulfill 2 independent tasks.